# CSS: change vertical align of h2 on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the vertical align of my h2 when my I mouse over the text, but it's not doing anything.

```css
    .evening:first-letter {
        vertical-align: 10%;
    }
    
    h2:hover {
        vertical-align: 0% !important;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
        <h2 class="evening">Evening</h2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing the `:first-letter` part on the hover selection:

```css
.evening:first-letter {
    vertical-align: 10%;
}

h2:hover:first-letter {
    vertical-align: 0% !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h2 class="evening">Evening</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the first-letter portion

```css
.evening:first-letter {
        vertical-align: 10%;
    }
    
    h2:hover:first-letter {
        vertical-align: 0% !important;
    }
```

```html
<div>
        <h2 class="evening">Evening</h2>
    </div>
```

Could achieve with just one css if you don't need any special styling for the first char.

```css
h2:hover:first-letter {
            vertical-align: 10%;
        }
```

```html
    <div>
            <h2 class="evening">Evening</h2>
        </div>
```